# What happens when you hold a reference to a stateless EJB on a long life object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Just a thought experiment. I know it is absolutely NOT how they are supposed to be used, but I want to know *how* the system would break or cause problems.

Imagine a session or an application scoped or any other kind of object which lifespan is longer than a request. Which has a @Stateless EJB field, received by constructor or a setter, and holds that reference forever.

What happens to that EJB and the container?

Answer (score 2):

Your "stateless EJB field" is a reference to a Stateless EJB.

However, it does not refer directly to the EJB instance. The referred object is a `proxy` for the EJB.

Every time you invoke a method through that proxy, the container creates or otherwise acquires a reference to an instance of the EJB and then invokes it. Containers may have a pool of these EJB instances so that it can acquire them quickly. It can do this because they are `Stateless` after all.

If you have:

```
public class Foo {

    @EJB
    private Bar myStatelessEJB;

    public void doSomething() {
        myStatelessEJB.eat();
        myStatelessEJB.something();
    }

}
```

Then each invocation of `myStatelessEJB` may call a completely different instance of `Bar`.

Therefore it makes no difference how long you keep the reference to the EJB. The container may forget it completely between calls or it may return it to a pool for other clients.

Comment: Interesting. So holding a reference on a singleton, for example, isn't such a horrible practice as I thought?

Comment: What? An [@javax.ejb.Singleton](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ejb/Singleton.html)? You did not ask about these.

Comment: No, I mean a normal one, written by hand.

Comment: If it's an `@Stateless` EJB then it is not a singleton.